# GemStone-Linux-Apache-Seaside-Smalltalk.. how practical is 4GB?

Tags: smalltalk, aero-glass, seaside, gemstone

I am really interested in [GLASS](http://seaside.gemstone.com/).  The 4GB limit for the free version has me concerned.  Especially when I consider the [price](http://seaside.gemstone.com/docs/GLASS-Announcement.htm) for the next level ($7000 year).

1. I know this can be subjective and variable, but can someone describe for me in everyday terms what 4 GB of GLASS will get you?  Maybe a business example.  4 GB may get me more storage than I realize.. and I don't have to worry about it.
2. In my app, some messages have file attachments up to 5 MB in size.  Can I conserve the 4 GB of Gemstone space by saving these attachments directly to files on the operating system, instead of inside Gemstone?  I'm thinking yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, there is no limit on the size of the repository. See the [latest specs](http://seaside.gemstone.com/docs/GLASS-Pricing-1201.htm) for GemStone

Comment: Thanks for the update Dale. I hadn't followed GLASS in sometime. That's a pretty impressive increase in the "free" capabilities. I like it!

Answer (score 6):

I'm aware of one GLASS system that is ~944 MB and has 8.3 million objects, or ~118 bytes per object. At this rate, it can grow to over 36 million objects and stay under 4 GB.

As to "attachments", I'd suggest that even in an RDBMS you should consider storing larger, static data in the file system and referencing it from the database. If you are building a web-based application, serving static content (JPG, CSS, etc.) should be done by your web server (e.g., Apache) rather than through the primary application.

By comparison, Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server have no-cost licenses for a 4-GB database.

What do you think would be a good price for the next level?

Comment: Thanks for reply. PRICE..  Speaking strictly from MY user standpoint, a good price would be something more along the lines of the EnterpriseDB model of Postgres pricing... ie basic system for free (all size db) but advanced features and support come with a cost.  BUT, I acknowledge pricing has many strategic implementations for the company.. and the free version may be a horrible choice for Gemstone et al.  Alternatively: could the free version have a 8 GB ceiling?  That's about the point where I think my app would be when I could convince my client that $7K is a prudent outlay of $.

Answer (score 4):

The 4GByte limit has been removed a while ago. The free version is [limited](http://glass.gemstone.com/docs/GLASS-Announcement.htm) now to the use of two cores and 2GByte ram.

Answer (score 3):

4GB is quite a decent size database. Not having used gemstone before I can only speculate as to how efficient it is a storing objects, but having played with a few other similar object databases (Mongodb, db4o). I know that you're going to be able to fit several(5-10) million records before you even get close to that limit. In reality, how many records depends highly on the type of data you're storing.

As an example I was storing ~2million listings & ~1million transactions, in a mysql database and the space was < 1Gb. You have a small overhead serializing a whole object, but not that much.

Files can definitely can be stored on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

4gb an issue... I guess you think you're building the next ebay!

Comment: Legal requirements for the app I want to build don't allow DELETE of data.  Instead of CRUD.. it is a CRU app.  So overtime, it will grow and grow; never shrink.  On any given day, only about 200 MB is the truly live data used by the enterprise... but the historical archived data needs to be readily accessible.  I haven't done extensive calculations, but I estimate about a year of operations before reaching 4GB.  I could get fancy and store the historical data in a parallel offline system.. but that adds complexity I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple simultaneous users with attachments of 5MB you need a separate strategy for them anyway, as each takes about a twentieth second of bandwidth of a GBit ethernet network.